# How to search Outlook mail for (zzz)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

Entering (zzz) in the search box returns emails with zzz. I want only emails with (zzz), i.e. the word with the parens around it. If I go to Advanced Find and enter (zzz) in the the Search for the word(s): text box, I get the same results. I also tried "zzz" ,/(zzz/) and backslash.

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1646919/how-to-search-for-symbols-special-characters-in-outlook-email-subject) which was never answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced Find should do it, at least it does for me in Outlook 365.

1. Open Advanced Find (Ctrl-Shift-F)
2. Click the Advanced Tab
3. From the `Field` drop-down choose Message (under Frequently Used)
4. Choose `contains` for Condition
5. Enter your search term `(zzz)` and click Add to List

[image]